# Records where value is not equal to current value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 7 `Departments` and an `Employee` that is assigned to 2 of them through a polymorphic join model called `DepartmentItem`. When I run the following I expect to get 5 records that the employee does not belong to, but instead I get all 7.

```php
$employee = \App\Employee::find(1);
$departments = \App\Department::join('department_items', 'department_items.department_id', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->select('departments.*')
    ->groupBy('departments.id')
    ->where('company_id', $employee->company_id)
    ->where('department_items.item_id', '!=', $employee->id)
    ->where('department_items.item_type', 'employee')
    ->get();
dd($departments);
```

This returns 7 departments when it should only return 5. When I change `'!='` to `'='` it returns the 2 departments that the employee is assigned to.

Here are the model relations:

```php
// Company
public function departments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Department::class);
}
public function employees() {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
}

// Department
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
public function employees() {
    return $this->morphedByMany(Employee::class, 'item', 'department_items');
}

// DepartmentItem
public function department() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
public function item() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}

// Employee
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<>` instead of `!=` as [`where clause`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) method takes mysql operators.

So your code should be like this:

```php
$departments = \App\Department::join('department_items', 'department_items.department_id', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->select('departments.*')
    ->groupBy('departments.id')
    ->where('company_id', $employee->company_id)
    ->where('department_items.item_id', '<>', $employee->id)
    ->where('department_items.item_type', 'employee')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried `'<>'` instead of `'!='` as well and it still returns all 7.

Comment: I think you should use `department_items.employee_id` instead of `department_items.item_id`! Let me know the result

Comment: I used the polymorphic relation because other records can belong to a `Department`, such as `Notes`. If I was looking for certain `Notes` that belong to a `Department` I would type `->where('department_items.item_id', [1, 2, 3])->where('department_items.item_type', 'note')`

Comment: You should use laravel's eloquent relationships in that case, wait for me so that I can update my answer!

Comment: I updated my question to add model relations info and syntax highlighting

Comment: Sorry, will let you know the answer by tomorrow. Can't help you with answer right now.